# Implicit conversions, type parameters, overloading, and anonymous functions syntax

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, implicits

So, I was trying to "pimp" my `Future`s (among other things) a little bit with something like this:

```
implicit class Pimp[T](val x: T) extends AnyVal  {
  def ->>[R](f: T => R): R = f(x)
  def ->>[R](r: => R): R = r
  def <<-(f: T => Unit): T = f.andThen(_ => x).apply(x)
  def <<-(f: => Unit): T = <<- { _ => f }
}
```

For some reason, when I try to do this now:

```
Future(1) ->> { Await.result(_, 1 seconds) }
```

it fails with `error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => Await.result(x$1, 1.seconds))`

But this works:

```
Future(1) <<- { Await.result(_, 1 seconds) }
```

So, the question is what is wrong with the first case. What am I doing wrong, and how to make it work. 
I even tried this (not at all what I want, because it is way too verbose): `Future(1) --> { case x: Future[Int] => Awayt.result(_, 1 seconds) }`, but even this fails for some reason (still says the parameter type is unknown - how is it unknown, if I explicitly specify it???)

I suspect, the difference between the first case and second is that `->>` has a type param, while `<<-` does not ... But even this `Future(1) ->>[Int] { Await.result(_, 1 seconds) }` still does not work :(

**Update** Ok, so, I found one way in which it works:

```
Future(1) ->> { (f:Future[Int]) => Await.result(f, 1 seconds) }
```

This kinda defeats the purpose of my implicit though, because of how verbose it is :( 
Is there any way to make it infer the parameter type without spelling it out like it does in the other case?

**Update 2** One more thing. Removing the overloaded "flavor" of `->>` from `Pimp` makes the other case work. I.e., if I only leave

```
def ->>[R](f: T => R): R = f(x)
```

in the definition of `Pimp`, then

```
Future(1) ->> { Await.result(_, 1 seconds) }
```

beautifully works as intended.

Having thought about it for a while, I think, that the problem is that in the overloaded case `foo ->> { _ => bar }` is ambiguous: it could mean "return bar", or "return a function foo => bar". This does not explain however why `foo ->>[Bar] { _ => bar }` does not work.

Comment: `Future(1) ->> {f => Await.result(f, 1 seconds) }` would be correct, but the type inference can't handle that.

Comment: The surprising part to me is that `<<-` works; leaving my understanding in a comment because it's clearly incomplete: Because there are overloads, there is no single "expected type", so the argument `{ Await.result(_, 1 seconds) }` needs to be typechecked on its own _before_ selecting an overload and in this case it obviously doesn't know the argument type.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov right, but `->>[Int]` should work then, because the expected type is unambigous, no?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov That flew right above my head :) But either way, I didn't mean to argue, this is not implemented according to the specification ... I am more like "why is specification not allowing it to infer the type in a case like this, when it is clear what it should be" :) FWIW, I was hoping that `->>[Int]` should make it work as if it was not overloaded ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten the call to `Future(1) ->> { Await.result(_: Future[Int], 1 seconds) }`. Not perfect, but better than your Update 1. Even better would be to avoid overloading in "pimped" methods: unsurprisingly, it complicates type inference.

After reading http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html carefully, it seems that specifying `[Int]` *shouldn't* work:

1. The entire expression is a function application (6.6).
2. Since `Future(1).->>` is overloaded, we go to 6.23.

   1. The set of alternatives A is the set of members referenced by `->>`; `[Int]` isn't taken into account, because the section talks about "identifier or selection `e`", and the selection is `Future(1).->>`.
   2. `shape({ Await.result(_, 1 seconds) })` is `Any => Nothing`.
   3. "Let B be the set of alternatives in A that are applicable to expressions (e1,…,en) of types (shape(e1),…,shape(en))". Both methods in A *are* applicable to `Any => Nothing` (as you say, "it could mean "return bar", or "return a function foo => bar"). So we go to "Otherwise, let S1,…,Sm be the vector of types obtained by typing each argument with an undefined expected type" and this typing fails.
   4. For the `<<-` case, `=> Unit` is not applicable (because the expected type is not `Unit` *at this step*, value discarding doesn't happen).

But it's subtle enough that I've changed my mind twice while writing this update; I *think* I've got it right now.

Comment: Yeah, I am removing the overloads, seems like it's "the lesser evil", although, it's unfortunate: my intent was to avoid typing things like `doSomething() ->> { _ => "Success" }` in favor of just `doSomething() ->> "Success"` :(